# How can I give this blob svg a scroll morph effect?

Tags: css, svg, blob

I currently have a blob in the background of my website and I'd like to morph it and make it interactive as the user scrolls down the page, what can I add to do this? ATM, the blob is animated but not on scroll.

Here is the html

```
<div class="morph-wrap">
              <svg class="morph" width="1400" height="770" viewBox="0 0 1400 770">
                    <path
                          d="M 262.9,252.2 C 210.1,338.2 212.6,487.6 288.8,553.9 372.2,626.5 511.2,517.8 620.3,536.3 750.6,558.4 860.3,723 987.3,686.5 1089,657.3 1168,534.7 1173,429.2 1178,313.7 1096,189.1 995.1,130.7 852.1,47.07 658.8,78.95 498.1,119.2 410.7,141.1 322.6,154.8 262.9,252.2 Z" />
              </svg>
        </div>
```

Here is the css

```
/* SVG Morph */
.morph-wrap {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.morph {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  fill: rgb(33, 33, 33);
  flex: none;
  animation: animate 5s linear infinite;

}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1) translate(10px, -30px);
  }

  38% {
    transform: scale(0.8, 1) translate(80vw, 30vh) rotate(160deg);
  }

  40% {
    transform: scale(0.8, 1) translate(80vw, 30vh) rotate(160deg);
  }

  78% {
    transform: scale(1.3) translate(0vw, 50vh) rotate(-20deg);
  }

  80% {
    transform: scale(1.3) translate(0vw, 50vh) rotate(-20deg);
  }

  100% {
    transform: scale(1) translate(10px, -30px);
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried any thing?, please show some code and the stack community will help out where ever you are stuck.

Comment: Update! I got it to work! I added "animation: animate 5s linear infinite;" to .morph and added: @keyframes animate {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1) translate(10px, -30px);
  }

  38% {
    transform: scale(0.8, 1) translate(80vw, 30vh) rotate(160deg);
  }

  40% {
    transform: scale(0.8, 1) translate(80vw, 30vh) rotate(160deg);
  }

  78% {
    transform: scale(1.3) translate(0vw, 50vh) rotate(-20deg);
  }

  80% {
    transform: scale(1.3) translate(0vw, 50vh) rotate(-20deg);
  }

  100% {
    transform: scale(1) translate(10px, -30px);
  }
}"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ You should make your comment into an answer to your question. If you do this it will be a lot easier to read PLUS, if you accept your own answer your SO reputation will get a boost! ; )